# Laravel como preencher um select com Eloquent?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.5

Estou usando o `Laravel 5.5` e tentando preencher um `input select` com o Eloquent e usando o seguinte código:

No `controller`:

```
$tipos = Tipo::pluck('nome', 'id');
return view('teste')->with('tipos', $tipos);
```

Na `view`:

```
{{Form::select('tipo_id',
               $tipos,
               $imovel->tipo_id,
               ['id'=>'myselect','class' =>'form-control'])}}
```

e desta maneira, cada item do `checkbox` vira um objeto da seguinte forma:

> `{"id":1,"nome":"casa","created_at":"2017-12-29 18:09:45","updated_at":"2017-12-29 18:09:45"}`

Como eu faço para que fique apenas o atributo `nome` no **item** e `id` no **value**?

Comment: Me parece que está correto não entendi o problema!

Comment: Na documentação do laravel [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) é usado de uma forma um pouco diferente. Lá é chamado adicionalmente `return view('teste')->with('tipos', $tipos->all());` que deveria retornar um array associativo, no formato `['chave1'=>valor1, 'chave2'=>valor2]`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o problema é que cada item do checkbox está vindo como um objeto, mas eu quero um array chave-valor em que o valor seja o nome e a chave o id. Não faz sentido mostrar pro usuário o objeto inteiro

Comment: @Juven_v mesmo usando $tipos->all(), ainda tenho o mesmo resultado, vc tem alguma outra ideia? to meio desesperado com isso

Comment: Você pode montar um laço for e criar o array desejado. Exemplo: `$arraytipos = []; foreach($tipos->all() as $tipo){$decode = json_decode($tipo); $arraytipos[$decode['id']] = $decode['nome']}` . Depois basta fazer `$tipos = $arraytipos;`. Não é a melhor abordagem, talvez você possa dar uma olha no [value](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers)

Comment: Form::select retornar um `select`? não entendi mesmo porque o código me parece ainda correto

Comment: Eu li, reli, mas, o `Form::select` retornar um caixa de seleção e não um `checkbox` e o `pluck` método do Eloquent, faz realmente o que precisa, ainda não entendi o seu problema ? tem como exemplificar o problema num exemplo minimo.

Answer (score -1):

Você terá que tratar o array passado para o select para que forme um novo array associativo. Sendo a chave o id e o nome o valor.

```
$tipos = Tipo::pluck('nome', 'id');
$tipo_associativo = [];
foreach($tipos as $key => $tipo){

        $tipo_associativo[$tipo['id']] = $tipo["nome"]; 
}
return view('teste')->with('tipos', $tipo_associativo);
```

agora quando você passar esse novo array para o Form::select:

```
{{Form::select('tipo_id',
           $tipos,
           $imovel->tipo_id,
           ['id'=>'myselect','class' =>'form-control'])}}
```

será montado o select da seguinte maneira:

```
<select name="tipo_id">
    <option value="id">nome</option>

</select>
```

Na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) ta um pouco resumido, mas da pra [encontrar outras fontes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field) que explica bem como criar um select com base em array.

Answer (score -1):

É muito simples!

No `controller` deve ficar desta forma:

Apenas inverta a ordem dos fatores e obtenha um resultado diferente. Não é necessário percorrer o objeto!

```
$tipos = Tipo::pluck('id', 'nome');
return view('teste')->with('tipos', $tipos);
```

Na `View` - Blade

```
{{Form::select('tipo_id',
           $tipos,
           $imovel->tipo_id,
           ['id'=>'myselect','class' =>'form-control'])}}
```